# how to add underline in string-array?

Tags: android, button, arrays

I have a string-array in strings.xml. How can I underline the string in item?

I've added like this in the string

```
<string-array name="myarray">
 <item> <Data> <![CDATA[ <u>Apple</u> ]]></Data> </item>`
<item> <Data> <![CDATA[ <u>Banana</u> ]]></Data> </item>
<item> <Data> <![CDATA[ <u>Orange</u> ]]></Data> </item>
```

and in the java file like this

```
final Button btn1;
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            ((Button) v).setText(q);


ArrayList<String> title_list = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] myarray_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);
String categoryAndDesc = null;
for(String cad : myarray_Array) {
  categoryAndDesc = cad;
  title_list.add(categoryAndDesc);
}
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(categoryAndDesc);

btn1.setText(squence);
btn1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
});
```

I will make a button that when clicked it will show random text taken from a string, What is wrong with the code above, please its support

Comment: You do realise the array you're referencing in your Java code is not the one you're showing in as xml resource example? `R.array.array != <string-array name="myarray">`.

Comment: oh yes I was wrong, and it is my edit. but in addition to the above error in the string array items appear one time only appears if the button onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
String[] myarray_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
String text =myarray_Array[0];
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(text);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 6, 11, 0);
textview.setText(content);
```

or you can use:

```
String[] myarray_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
String text =myarray_Array[0];
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(""+"<u>" +text+ "</u>));
```

Comment: It worked but only once onclick and click the button can not be in for a second time

Answer (score 0):

```
<string-array name="description">
     <item> Check this &lt;u&gt;Redirect to Next Activity&lt;/u&gt; </item>
</string-array>
```

IN CODE YOU CAN USE IT AS....

```
String[] myarray_Array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
String text =myarray_Array[0];
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

you can try the above solution as an alternate...

Comment: and what should I add in the java file

Comment: in jave you can simply use that array.